# Error after installing NPM for node.js

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, npm

After installing npm I get the following error report

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ 'node', '/home/ash/local/bin/npm' ]
info using npm@1.0.30
info using node@v0.4.12
verbose config file /home/ash/.npmrc
verbose config file /home/ash/local/etc/npmrc
ERR! Error: ENOENT, No such file or directory
ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
ERR! or email it to:
ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
ERR! 
ERR! System Linux 2.6.38-11-generic
ERR! command "node" "/home/ash/local/bin/npm"
ERR! cwd /home/ash
ERR! node -v v0.4.12
ERR! npm -v 1.0.30
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have installed node and npm using the method outlined in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1232821) using the "git all the way method". However I changed the directory locations for the npm and node repos.

It is set up like so

```
~/
    Apps/
    Dev/
        node/   << node repo
        npm/    << npm repo
    local/  << default setup location as outlined in the gist
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong here.

**EDIT**

Bash history

```
$ mkdir ~/local
$ echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
$ . ~/.bashrc

$ cd Apps/Dev/node
$ ./configure --prefix=~/local
$ make install

$ cd ../npm
$ sudo PATH=~/local/bin:$PATH make install
$ export PATH=~/local/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Could you please provide your bash history of the install steps?

Comment: I have added the bash history

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar problem:

> https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1004
>
> As it turns out it's not a very good idea to have "bin" listed in the
>   ~/.gitignore file (it will exclude the npm/bin from the install
>   package)
>
> I hadn't touched my ~/.gitignore in the last 2 years maybe - turns out
>   it was full of rather dumb stuffs. Spring cleaning ~/.gitignore took
>   care of the problem. Mission accomplished, npm v1.0.9-1 is now
>   successfully installed (phew)

ALSO:  Do you have a directory "/home/ash/local/etc/npmrc"?